# How to generate code-coverage info from VS2010 solution with Intel Fortran projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fortran, code-coverage, intel

The clue is in the title really but I'm struggling to get code coverage for a mixed solution (C#,C++,Fortran). The C# drops out easily and I believe native C++ is supported to a degree but I can't work out how to get figures for the Fortran? any ideas? apparently Intel's given me a "code coverage tool" but I can't find it.

Comment: ahhh, looks like the tool is called: "codecov.exe"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tool is indeed called codecov.exe
Fro anyone googling here, this is the switch: [qprof-gen](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/composerxe/en-us/cpp/mac/index.htm#copts/common_options/option_prof_genx.htm)